# Microsoft Ado.Net Data Entity Model

Tags: entity

I have Visual Studio 2010 and Oracle Client installed on my 64 bit Windows 7 machine. In the Server Explorer, I can add a new connection using ODP.NET data provider, and test it successfully. I can also use the query window to run commands using that connection. The problem occurs when I try to add ADO.NET Entity Data Model using (right-click) Add New Item to the solution.  Entity Data Model Wizard opens and I choose Generate from database. The  next page does NOT show the connection to Oracle that I added from Server Explorer. If I try to add a new connection from this window, Oracle is not an option in Choose a DataSource window. If I select Other, then ODP.NET does not appear in the dropdown for Data Provider. What do I need to do to get the Oracle connection and/or ODP.NET provider to show up in the EDM Wizard? Here is the VS 2010 configuration on my machine.
I have oracle client 12.1. and visual studio 2015

Comment: Please add more information.

Comment: @Norrius What have you tried so far? What are the errors? Provide example of code please.

Comment: @ApoloRadomer you pinged the wrong person lol

Comment: @Norrius Amazing attention to detail here :P